# AsyncTask in custom EditText

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-edittext

So I'm a bit puzzled. I'm using the TextWatcher afterTextChanged(Editable s) method to search thru the text that the user enters and detect if he typed one of the word of a list and if yes to add a span to that position.

When I tried to implement it directly in the afterTextChanged, as the text grows it harder to search it and span the specific words, so I moved the work on an AsynkTask class. Here is the class:

```
 class SearchText extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private String match = "(\\d )?(([\\p{Alnum}\\p{Punct}])+?) ([0-9]+?)\\b:([0-9]+?)(, ([0-9]+?))?(-([0-9]+?))?\\b";
    private Editable s;

    SearchText(Editable s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(match).matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            Reference reference = new Reference(m.group(9));
            if (booksList.contains(m.group(2)) && mListener.check(reference)) {

                BooksSpan booksSpan = new BooksSpan("1");
                try {
                    s.setSpan(booksSpan, m.start(), m.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`s.setSpan(booksSpan, m.start(), m.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);` when I type really fast, like random words, it gives me:

`Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Why is this just sometimes? Editable is not a view. What am I missing?

Comment: I am not sure why this happens only sometimes. But when using AsyncTask you should use `onPostExecute()` to manipulate UI.

Comment: How is Editable UI?

Comment: Show the complete stacktrace.

Comment: that was only a quick guess... I could not reproduce your problem with a simplified version of your code. I guess the error comes from somewhere else. What does `mListener.check(reference)` do?

Comment: I need to correct myself! I CAN reproduce your problem! (Just needed to type faster). I will write an Answer.

Comment: mListener.check(reference) for now it's just returning true, it's not implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with following simplified code:

```
class SearchText extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private String match = "t";
    private Editable s;

    SearchText(Editable s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(match).matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            try {
                s.replace(m.start(), m.end(), "A");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I type really fast, the exception is thrown, as you described.
When I change the code to following, it works without problems:

```
 class SearchText extends AsyncTask<String, String, Map<Integer, Integer>> {
    private String match = "t";
    private Editable s;

    SearchText(Editable s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<Integer, Integer> doInBackground(String... params) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(match).matcher(s);
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        while (m.find()) {
            map.put(m.start(), m.end());
        }
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<Integer, Integer> result) {
        for (Integer i : result.keySet()) {
            try {
                s.replace(i, result.get(i), "AAAA");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the solution is to perform the manipulation of the Editable in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: onPostExecute runs in UI an it's not ok because it will slow down when the text is big

Comment: the only solution I thing that will work is to make sure that the async is called max 1 time per 500 mils,

Comment: I'm combined our answer and I think is a good compromise. I run the change in onPostExecute, but the asynk is only called once every 1000 milis, so Thanks